# How to install Haskell Control Lens

Tags: haskell

I've noticed that Control.Lens is not part of Haskell platform, so I probably need to install it.

Can anyone explain how to install it? Is it not really part of Haskell platform?

Edit: I'm using GHCi, and it uses prelude.

Comment: `Control.Lens` comes from the [lens package on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens). You can easily include packages from Hackage using Cabal, Stack, or direct download.

Comment: Are you sure your question isn't "How do I add the `Control.Lens` module to a GHCi session"? If it is, the answer is `:m + Control.Lens`.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs It's not. Problem is OP doesn't know what packages are

Comment: @Cubic, I used import Control.Lens,  my the script, but I think I need to install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Warning: this answer only works for cabal versions prior to version 3.0.0.0

see [lens tutorial](http://lens.github.io/tutorial.html)

```
$ cabal install lens
```

Comment: @user4564798 Prelude is the default module imported in Haskell. It has nothing to do with your ability to install packages.

Comment: `apt-get install libghc-lens-dev` on debian/ubuntu

Comment: Thank you guys, I used your ideas and this is how I installed it  "  :! cabal install lens "

Comment: This no longer works now the v2 commands are the default.