# How to import Control.Lens in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, import, haskell-lens

I am new to Haskell. I want to use Control.Lens package. I've read  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44828264/how-to-install-haskell-control-lens) and applied what it says but I get an error that says:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal-3.6.2.0.exe: Cannot build the executables in the package lens because it
does not contain any executables. Check the .cabal file for the package and
make sure that it properly declares the components that you expect.
```

when I try to run `cabal install lens` in the project folder.(I opened terminal in the project folder.)

Any help would be appreciated.

**Solution:** I've learned that I need to add *'lens'* into *build-depends* part of .cabal file.Then I need to import *Control.Lens* inside *Main.hs* . I give my .cabal file as an example:

```
executable Prelude3
main-is:          Main.hs

-- Modules included in this executable, other than Main.
--other-modules: Basic

-- LANGUAGE extensions used by modules in this package.
-- other-extensions:
build-depends:  containers,lens,microlens,microlens-platform,base ^>=4.14.3.0
hs-source-dirs:   app
default-language: Haskell2010
```

On the top of the Main.hs I write *import Control.Lens*. Finally after I run 'cabal build' and *cabal run* in the terminal necessary packages successfully downlaoaded.

Comment: That answer is outdated. See [the GHCup first steps](https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/steps) for a modern guide to package management.